# Prove derivation of global minimum of a convex function is zero (using only convexity)

Tags: derivatives, optimization, convex-analysis

I am reading the [Wikipedia of Convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function). in it, it is written:

> if $f$ is a convex function then $$ f(x) \ge f(y) + f'(y)(x-y)$$
>   for all $x$ and $y$ in the interval. In particular, if $f ′(c) = 0$, then $c$
>   is a global minimum of $f(x)$.

I fully understand this, but I'm wondering if it is possible to prove that if $c$ if the point of the minimum then $f ′(c) = 0$ just by using convexity. I think it is possible but until now I could not prove that.

Comment: If $c$ is a (local) minimum then $f'(c)=0$ for any differentiable function without convexity. Do you mean to prove the other way round?

Comment: @A.Γ. yes I mean to prove that just by the definition of convex functions.

Comment: Is your question [Fermat's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)#Statement)?

Comment: @A.Γ. not it is not. see, I know that for any function If c is a (local) minimum then $f′(c)=0$. but in this case, I want to prove that for convex functions just by using its definition, and I don't know why I can't. I think there must be a way to prove that easily for both functions of one variable and functions of $n$ variables.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. If $c$ is a $\min$ of any function (on an open set) then $f'(x) = 0$. This has nothing to do with convexity.

Comment: If $f(x) \ge f(c)$ for all $x$ then the above inequality shows that $f'(c) (x-c) \le 0$ for all $x$ and hence $f'(c) = 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat, yes yes you made it! thank you. what a nice answer.

Comment: @copper.hat, I think it has some mistakes. if $f(x)≥f(c)$ then $f(x)≥f(c)+f′(c)(x−c)$ so $f(x)-f(c) ≥ f′(c)(x−c)$ there $ f(x)-f(c) ≥ 0$. how you come to $f′(c)(x−c)≤0$  for all x?

Comment: @Peyman: You are correct, that was sloppy of me.

Comment: Your statement is false (the minimum could be on the boundary of the domain). The statement on Wikipedia is true.